# There was nothing to do than watching films

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, grammaticality, phrases

I was writing something and I made a sentence 'There was nothing to do than watching films.' Is the usage of 'than' in this sentence correct? I kind of remember 'than' can be used the same way as 'except' and 'except for'. So, I rewrote the sentence like 'There was nothing to do except(or except for) watching films' and kind of felt like it was accurate. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you're missing an "other" in there, for the initial sentence to make sense: "There was nothing to do *other than* watching films."